# Not able to execute the stored procedure

Tags: sql, datetime, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have table in which my date column value is saved with time also

like this **2016-06-10 14:56:11.000**

Now while executing my SP, I pass one parameter as date like this `exec UserReportData '06-10-2016'` but it is not showing any records. As it has 4 records in the table.

Why?

**UPDATE**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserReportData] 
    @As_ONDATE Datetime 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @REPORTDATE datetime        
    DECLARE @OPENING INT        

    SELECT * 
    INTO #temptable
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
             a.CUser_id, b.User_Id,a.U_datetime as REPORTDATE, 
             b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name AS USERNAME,
             0 OPENING, 0 TOTAL_DOCUMENT, 0 INWARD, 0 FIRST_LEVEL_PROCESSING, 0 DATA_ENTRY
         FROM 
             inward_doc_tracking_trl a, user_mst b
         WHERE
             a.CUser_id = b.mkey
             AND a.U_datetime = CONVERT(varchar(10), @As_ONDATE, 103)) AS x

    DECLARE Cur_1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT CUser_id, User_Id 
        FROM #temptable

    OPEN Cur_1

    DECLARE @CUser_id INT
    DECLARE @User_Id INT

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @REPORTDATE  
        FROM inward_doc_tracking_trl                        
        WHERE U_datetime = CONVERT(varchar(10), @As_ONDATE, 103)

        UPDATE #temptable
        SET REPORTDATE = @REPORTDATE
        WHERE CUser_id = @CUser_id
          AND User_Id = @User_Id

        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id
    END

    CLOSE Cur_1
    DEALLOCATE Cur_1

    SELECT * 
    FROM #temptable

    DROP TABLE #temptable
END
```

Comment: Can you post the procedure code?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a date as a string (with implicit time being 00:00) which you are casting to be a date, still with time being 00:00, and trying to match dates with times.  There won't be any results as the time doesn't match.

You have to either:

1. Cast the datetime to a date to match an exact date (not good, requires recalculating every date in the column)
2. Change the search to look between date + '00:00' to date + '23:59' (or if you are happy, you could just add a day)

Update for your where clause to take the easy option 2:

```
where a.CUser_id = b.mkey
   and a.U_datetime BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(10), @As_ONDATE, 103) 
                    AND DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(varchar(10), @As_ONDATE, 103))
```

Comment: added your answer, but still not getting any records

Comment: @NK try calling the SP with the date as '10-06-2016'

Comment: it ran but with error as `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'REPORTDATE', table 'tempdb.dbo.#temptable`

Comment: @NK looks like the code in the cursor is causing the problem.  What are you trying to do, as currently you have a cursor which is updating row by row, that is normally a bad design, you should just have an update statement.  The error is because in the cursor, you are doing the same search you had before and aren't finding a record.  You can make it the same type of search, but if there is more than one record then it won't work correctly.

Comment: yes the cursor is causing problem. See what I want is. I want to add `REPORTDATE`, `USERNAME`, `OPENING`, `......` from the `inward_doc_tracking_trl` which all has some conditions with parameters as today's date

Comment: @NK you should look at rewriting as a single update statement if possible.  Currently, you are reading a date, then trying to update it in a temp table (where the definition is set as the columns you are reading from) but you are not finding a value to update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114345/discussion-between-n-k-and-cjk).

Comment: if possible come on chat, i will explain u in detail